# Parsing Json Data to in Grid view having RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, gridview, android-recyclerview

I am referring to this tuto [link](http://www.exoguru.com/android/ui/recyclerview/custom-android-grids-using-recyclerview.html) . I want to get json data from server in this grid view..please tell me how to parse data. plus i need to cache those images..using volley library or so.
 any link our tuto you can provide to parse??? please suggest me fast

Answer (score 0):

Using Volley parsing your data can be achieved like this :

1. Create class VolleyService
   public class VolleyService {

   ```
   private static VolleyService instance;
   private RequestQueue requestQueue;
   private ImageLoader imageLoader;

   private VolleyService(Context context) {
       requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

       imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue, new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
           private final LruCache<String, Bitmap> cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

           @Override
           public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
               return cache.get(url);
           }

           @Override
           public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
               cache.put(url,bitmap);
           }
       });
   }

   public static VolleyService getInstance(Context context) {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = new VolleyService(context);
       }
       return instance;
   }

   public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
       return requestQueue;
   }

   public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
       return imageLoader;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Use it like this for creating the request and getting the JSON response for your URL:

   RequestQueue queue =

   ```
       VolleyService.getInstance(this.getContext()).getRequestQueue();    
       StringRequest request = new StringRequest(url, new 
       Response.Listener<String>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(String response) {
               // we got the response, now our job is to handle it
               try {
                   updateArticleData(response, syncResult,categoryID);
               } catch (RemoteException | OperationApplicationException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
       }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

           @Override
           public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               //something happened, treat the error.
               Log.e("Error", error.toString());
           }
       });

       queue.add(request);
   ```
3. Mehod getJsonFromResponse(response) :

   ```
    private SomeClass getDataFromJson(String json) {     
       //Do sth with json    
       return someData;
   }
   ```